# What will happen if send message to handler whose activity has been unvisible?

Tags: android, multithreading, handler

I create a handler in activity onCreate method,and start a background thread.In the background thread,I will invoke the handler's sendMessage method(in handler's handleMessage method,I update the activity's UI),but the activity may has been unvisible,what will happen?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't do anything UI-related in that handler, it'll execute fine. Keep in mind that holding references to inactive Activity could create a memory leak - you'll prevent the VM from collecting unused resources.

Comment: If do anything UI-related in that handler?what will happen?Exception will throw?

Comment: Yes, WindowManager.BadTokenException

Comment: AFAIK, it won't throw any exception. But when you will resume the application, it will execute all the UI related statements. This will add some delay while resuming, and you will see black screen when these statements are executed.

Comment: @Karan: What does "resume the application" mean? How would be possible for the Handler to inspect whether it'll run UI-related "statements" or not? Don't post wrong information, people might mess their apps if they read it. Just send a Runnable that shows AlertDialog to a Handler in invisible Activity's main thread and see what happens

Comment: Try this out : Add a textview in your activity and update this in a Hanlder recursively and see what happens.

Comment: Btw if you don't know, AlertDialog will create a new window that is why you are getting the BadTocketnException. If you have not tried everything, then don't post any wrong information.

Comment: Sorry dude, you're not making sense. I bet nobody can't explain what does "Add a textview in your activity and update this in a Hanlder recursively" mean...